# Routing for Ajax post to a Controller method MVC 4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Needing to receive a post from ajax and throw it into my controller method. Ajax is outputting correct values.

I created a api conrtoler called ArticleScore. In the controller I want to through the values from ajax into the method SaveRating:

```
    [HttpPost]
    private static int SaveRating(int articleID, int rate)
```

Here's my Ajax:

```
         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveRating","ArticleScore")',
                data: JSON.stringify({ articleID: artID, rate: v }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                        alert("success");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("I'm AJAX and I don't like to work");
                }
            });
```

I was told by my teacher to use routing. So in my global.asax I entered the following from an article I read:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Rating",                                           // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{articleID/{rate}",                            // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "ArticleScore", action = "SaveRating", articleID = "", rate = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

However it is not working. I believe it is my URL parameters in my maproute.

Answer (score 0):

I use ajax calls a lot and haven't had to change my routing.  I just use the default.  On your controller I use static for calls that I make from the view (populate a drop down for example)
so try changing your method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveRating(int articleID, int rate)
```

just noticed your controller is also private which makes it so they ajax call can't see it.  make sure it is changed to public